# SharePoint 2013 MySite "LIKED" link to publishing page

Tags: 2013, mysite

[Simon J.K. Pedersen](http://wp.sjkp.dk/sharepoint-2013-add-like-functionality-to-publishing-page-with-javascript/) has a nice way to add LIKE functionality to a publishing page. This functionality works great. I have also implemented like functionality on simple list items as well as described in [Cato Auestad](https://coderwall.com/p/urb8kg) article.

The issue I am having is when the "LIKED" content shows up on a user's MySite activity feed. If a user clicks on a page link the users lands on the pub page item property page (item -> Pages/Forms/DispForm.aspx).

Is there anyway to have users directed to the actual publishing page when clicking on the link in the activity feed?

[image]